# Выбор элемента jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

Есть 3 селекта

```
<div class="wrapper_prods">
<div id="id" style="display: none">1</div>
<select id="test">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="1">3</option>
</select>
<div id="#text"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper_prods">
<div id="id" style="display: none">2</div>
<select id="test">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="1">3</option>
</select>
<div id="#text"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper_prods">
<div id="id" style="display: none">3</div>
<select id="test">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="1">3</option>
</select>
<div id="#text"></div>
</div>
```

При изменении данных на любом из селектов нужно вывести его #id в его #text

для этого использую что то на подобие

```
<script>
$('#test').change(function() {
        var numberp=$(this).closest('.wrapper_prods').find('#id').html();
        var op=$('#test').val();
        alert(numberp);
  });
</script>
```

Но выводит только когда изменяю первый селект, когда же изменяю 2 или 3 ничего не происходит, оно банально не видит их ИД, что делать?

Comment: ID уникальный и должен быть в единственном числе. В вашем случае используйте класс. Вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/CVLnW/

Answer (score 2):

Для начала почитайте документацию. 
Идентификатор объекта должен быть уникальным, не уникальным может быть только "класс" объекта.
А у вас **id="test"** для для всех селектов!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[id=test]").each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    obj.change(function() {
        var numberp=$(this).closest('.wrapper_prods').find('#id').html();
        var op=$('#test').val();
        alert(numberp);
    });    
})
```

[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/IVsevolod/Anzvm/)

**НО** Так делать не надо! Так как это плохо давать одинаковые id элементам.

Comment: Зачем вы позволяете автору оперировать с несколькими элементами с одинаковым id?

Comment: @Genson я просто сказал, что можно по одинаковым id сделать селекты.., но я соглашусь что **одинаковые id делать Очень и Очень Плохо**!

Comment: На мой взгляд, лучше вообще не приводить примеры плохих практик где это не требуется, а сразу демонстрировать одно из допустимых решений. Одно из таких я привёл.

Answer (score 0):

Измените `id="id"` на `class="id"`.
Мне недавно это помогло.